# Why is a machine's ssh key required to clone a public Git repository?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I think for clone a private repo, we need to verify the computer is trusted. But for a public repo, not sure why git is designed to ask for ssh key for a machine if the ssh key is not added in Settings of github?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you connect via SSH, Git (actually the SSH agent used by Git) will **always** require authentication in form of a private key. This is because the SSH protocol actually does not care whether you're accessing a public or private repository.

You can easily determine the protocol that's used for cloning by looking at the remote URL. SSH urls look like this:

1. `ssh://git@github.com/<user>/<repo>.git`
2. `git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git`

However, on GitHub you can always clone public repositories using the `git://` protocol instead of `ssh://`, which does not require authentication:

```
git clone git://github.com/<user>/<repo>.git
```

Alternatively, use HTTPS, which will (if memory serves) require authentication only for private repositories:

```
git clone https://github.com/<user>/<repo>.git
```

Answer (score 8):

Git will need a ssh key only if you are using ssh protocol - there doesn't exist such a thing as anonymous ssh, ssh needs a key (an account) to work.

If you use `git` or `https` protocol, no ssh key is needed. If you don't want to use accounts / authentication, `git` protocol might be your best bet.

([More information on git protocols](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols))