# How to git pull from public repo via ssh without a key?

Tags: git, github

I have a public repo, https://github.com/rlpowell/config .  I used to be able to run git pull without any ssh keys (i.e. from cron), and it work work fine, using the git@github.com:rlpowell/config.git URL (i.e. the SSH URL).  This no longer works, and I've no idea why, but it *does* work for two of my friends.

I would like to be able to git pull a public repo without an ssh key, or at least understand why it doesn't work for me and does for other people.

Here's a friend trying my test case:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:rlpowell/config.git  ; cd config ; (unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK ; ssh-add -l ; git pull )
Cloning into 'config'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.253.113' to the list of known hosts.
remote: Counting objects: 1061, done.
remote: Total 1061 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1061
Receiving objects: 100% (1061/1061), 544.42 KiB | 495.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (632/632), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
Already up-to-date.
```

And here's me doing exactly the same thing:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:rlpowell/config.git  ; cd config ; (unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK ; ssh-add -l ; git pull )
Cloning into 'config'...
remote: Counting objects: 1061, done.
remote: Total 1061 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1061
Receiving objects: 100% (1061/1061), 544.42 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (632/632), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
Enter passphrase for key '/home/rlpowell/.ssh/id_rsa':
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

(I hit enter at the ssh key password prompt).

In the repo, the .git/config is:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github.com:rlpowell/config.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

And git config -l is:

```
$ git config -l
user.email=rlpowell@digitalkingdom.org
user.name=Robin Lee Powell
push.default=matching
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=git@github.com:rlpowell/config.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

git version is 2.5.5

strace says the thing actually running ssh is

```
ssh git@github.com git-upload-pack 'rlpowell/config.git'
```

Comment: One possibility is that, for some reason, your SSH key in GitHub is out of sync with what you have locally.  Follow [these instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/) to update your key in GitHub.

Comment: I think that your assumption that it's possible to clone/pull without a key is wrong (see [docs](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/#cloning-with-ssh-urls)). Just look at the output your friend gets: `... Could not open a connection to your authentication agent. ...`; this proves that SSH key is used in that case. Your friends probably just don't have passphrases on their keys. Consider using HTTPS protocol if you don't want authentication.

Comment: We checked the passphrase thing.  I can git clone without a key, but not pull.  2 of my friends can clone and pull.  One of my friends can neither clone nor pull.  There's something deeper going on.

Comment: If I understand correctly, SSH always performs authentication and hence requires your key. Try additionally temporary renaming `~/.ssh` directory or using different user account to be sure that nothing interferes.

Comment: could you try the same two session with `GIT_TRACE=2` set before? (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#Debugging)

Comment: "...or at least understand why it doesn't work for me and does for other people." Did you check if your friends have set up SSH keys? https://github.com/settings/keys they are independent of the project, so that could be the reason for why its working for some of them.

Comment: @rlpowell I think VonC's answer comes closest to the reasoning? Is it valid?

Answer (score 20):

I just tried it without key, and I confirm it cannot work (without SSH key):

```
$ git clone git@github.com:rlpowell/config.git
Cloning into 'config'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

That is because GitHub won't authorize anonymous access through SSH (as opposed to https), as other git repo servers decided to do ([like Gogits](https://github.com/gogits/gogs/issues/1222) or [go-gitea](https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/issues/2169))

GitHub [does mention](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/#cloning-with-ssh-urls):

> SSH URLs provide access to a Git repository via SSH, a secure protocol.
>   To use these URLs, you **must** [generate an SSH keypair](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key) on your computer and add the public key to your GitHub account.

(emphasis on *must*)

[Why? (asked in 2015)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30989804/6309). While [sshd can be configured to allow anonymous access](https://askubuntu.com/a/583153/5470), no public site would ever consider setting this up: it is too big of a security risk.

> needs to work without a specific key

If you need anonymous access, you can use:

- an https URL
- a git URL: `git://github.com/<user>/<repo>`, although it uses the port 9418, which is often blocked in an enterprise environment.

Answer (score 13):

try run this command first :

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no github.com
```

and then `git pull` again.

Comment: `$ ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no github.com
Permission denied (publickey).`

Answer (score 5):

It is a public GitHub repo and you just want to pull from it, so you can use the HTTPS URL instead:

```
https://github.com/rlpowell/config.git
```

[image: https://github.com/rlpowell/config.git]

Answer (score 4):

Problem seem to be with ssh keys, at least response saing it:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/rlpowell/.ssh/id_rsa':
Permission denied (publickey).
```

So you need to add your public key to github

[Adding a new SSH key to your GitHub account](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/)

Also you can run :

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

to check ssh connection to github

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of how ssh works and how ssh keys interact with github; the point is that you don't need an ssh key to clone or pull a public repo, except that I do.  Did you try the test code I gave?

Answer (score 2):

For public repo's you don't need any password. You can directly clone using their https link :

eg `git clone https://github.com/rlpowell/config.git`

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't do this using SSH. Here is a good explanation:

[GitHub protocol comparison](https://gist.github.com/grawity/4392747)

If you want to clone and pull the stuff without any key use HTTP(S).

So with

```
git clone http://github.com/rlpowell/config.git
Klone nach 'config' ...
warning: Leite nach https://github.com/rlpowell/config.git/ um
remote: Counting objects: 1234, done.
remote: Total 1234 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1234
Empfange Objekte: 100% (1234/1234), 2.01 MiB | 1.07 MiB/s, Fertig.
Löse Unterschiede auf: 100% (758/758), Fertig.
```

the ".git/config" will look like this:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = http://github.com/rlpowell/config.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

You can change that file later on if you already cloned or use `git config`

With those settings you can `git pull` at any time.

Why using the url `git@github.com:rlpowell/config.git` does not work is due to the following reason:

The entry `git@github.com:rlpowell` will force you to authenticate using SSH. Github requires you to use keypairs if you want SSH authentication.

If you want to have an automatic cronjob user and still use SSH, create as that user a keypair and upload the public one to gitlab.

But if you only want to clone and pull, HTTPS will be more than enough. By the way, authentation via HTTPS is also possible. Github asks for your username and password if you try to push changes. This of course is not recommended, if you are using cronjobs.

Answer (score 1):

You have issue with your certificate.
the easy solution is simply to create a new one and replace the old one.

The problem can be caused by several issues for example: wrong host file entry, invoked ssh certificate and more.

so the best thing is to create a new certificate and test it.

Simply follow those steps and you will set up your ssh key in no time:

- Generate a new ssh key (or skip this step if you already have a key)
  `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your@email"`
- Once you have your key set in `home/.ssh` directory (or `Users/<your user>.ssh` under windows), open it and copy the content

---

#### How to add sh key to github account?

- Login to github account
- Click on the rancher on the top right (Settings)
  [image: github account settigns]
- Click on the `SSH keys`
  [image: ssh key section]
- Click on the `Add ssh key`
  [image: Add ssh key]
- Paste your key and save

And you all set to go :-)

Comment: Again, the point is that it should be possible to pull *without* any ssh key.  I've done it before, clone works without an ssh key, and my friends can do it without any ssh keys available (it doesn't even ask them for their main key password).

Comment: Ok. Thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

You *cannot* connect to an SSH server without authenticating.

Thus it's *impossible* to clone or pull over SSH without a registered SSH key.

You have two options:

- Run the cron job as a user who has an SSH key that is associated with a GitHub account (you can use a config file to point at a specific key file if you want).
- Use HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

Others have mentioned that you can use `https` for fetching data without authentication (for public github repos). But that is obviously a problem when you want to push data occasionally too (for which you *need* authentication).

What you may want is to use unauthenticated `https` URL for fetching data, and authenticated `ssh` URL for pushing data - and both git and github support that, i.e.:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://github.com/rlpowell/config.git
        pushurl = git@github.com:rlpowell/config.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

you can also change and verify it from command line:

```
% git remote set-url origin https://github.com/rlpowell/config.git
% git remote set-url origin --push git@github.com:rlpowell/config.git

% git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/rlpowell/config.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:rlpowell/config.git (push)
```

After that, `git pull` won't be asking for authentication, but `git push` will

(taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73836045/2600099))