# is it considered bad practice to create ssh key in container?

Tags: git, docker, ssh, containers, ssh-keys

I have a container which pulls a public repo from github and it requires ssh key inside it. I'm thinking of generating ssh key inside container but I'm seeing some posts arguing that leaving ssh keys inside container can impose security vulnerability. So I'm wondering what is the best approach here?

1. Using VOLUME API to leave key in host file system
2. Generating key in container and leave it there
3. Using COPY or ADD API to copy key from host to container

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For public repos on Github, you don't need a ssh key to clone or pull.

Comment: I believe this is not true. If you are connecting via ssh, key needs to be present. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989718/why-is-a-machines-ssh-key-required-to-clone-a-public-git-repository @HeronYang

Comment: That is correct. You can use https protocol instead if that meets your need.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to use ssh connection. Sorry to mention that in the question.@Heron Yang

Comment: Back to your question, a better reason for generating a key per container may be needed. As you are pulling a public repo, there's no need to assign a key for this container. By not assigning a key, there's almost none security issue to concern. But, anyway, if you are generating a ssh key per container, and it is only being used for pulling a public repo, there's no security concern as well since the key can't be used in any other place. That is, if you are distributing the container and the key will be used for other purposes, that's where the problems starts.

Comment: @Heron Yang okay sounds great. Thanks for the response!